# Compiler error when the returning type has expression parameters (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

I'm having troubles with template expression parameters. My code is running well in gcc and clang but it's failing to compile in Visual Studio with the error: "unable to match function definition to an existing declaration."

I narrowed problematic code to something very small but I can't understand the reason of the error. It seems that using `Dim` in expression parameter of the return type is causing the problems. I fixed it by adding `typedef Foo<Dim> Foo` inside Bar but I want to know the reason for the error. Should that code compile? Is there any reason the typedef makes a difference?

```
#include <iostream>

template <int _Dim>
struct Foo{
  enum {Dim = _Dim};
  int i = Dim;
  };

template <typename T>
struct Bar{
  enum {Dim = T::Dim};
  Foo<Dim> fun();
  };

template<typename T>
Foo<Bar<T>::Dim> Bar<T>::fun()
  {
  return Foo<Bar<T>::Dim>();
  }

int main() {
    Bar<Foo<3>> myBar;
    std::cout <<myBar.fun().i <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If someone has a better idea for the name of the question I would also appreciate a comment.

Comment: This code should compile, VS is not able to deal with `Bar<T>::Dim` when `Dim` it is not a type name.